# Swift - Exit function with background thread inside

Tags: swift, multithreading, function, return, background-process

I have a function that does some looping in the background and update the UI:

```
func doSomething() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        for ... {
            if ... {
                ...
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //Update UI
                    ...

                    if ... {
                        // Show UIAlert
                        //Exit function
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to exit the function (hence cancelling the background thread). If I use `return`, the alert shows up but the background thread keeps looping data to the end. I think the reason is that when swapping to the main thread, I am out of scope of the function.

I am new to Swift multi-threading, so any Idea?

Comment: Depending on all of the `...` code, the `for` loop may finish very, very quickly, long before most of the calls to update the UI are actually run. You probably need to show more of the details to get a specific solution.

Comment: You're right. I was confused why the alert was processed many times even after the the condition for the `for` loop is satisfied. I changed `async` in the `main` dispatch to `sync` and it is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know if you want to stop execution of ***for*** loop which is running on background thread, then you have to stop it from background thread itself which you are trying to stop from main thread block of code. try something line below :

```
func doSomething() {

var continueForLoop = true

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    for ... {
        if ... && continueForLoop{
            ...
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                //Update UI
                ...

                if ... {
                    // Show UIAlert
                    //Exit function
                    continueForLoop = false
                }
            }
        }else{
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

P.S. to understand multithreading in iOS go thought this link : [iOS Concurrency](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/) Note: try to understand the multithreading part only as code contains old swift syntaxes.

Comment: More than likely this won't help any. The `for` loop will probably be finished long before you have a chance to set `continueForLoop = false`. But it all depends on what code is really in those `...`.

Comment: This was easy and the link is helpful. I just changed the `async` to `sync` in the main dispatch to stop executing the alert. Thanks.